# Select multiple counts with different conditions and only count distinct, returning results in a single row

Tags: sql, impala

I have seen a lot of questions on how to select multiple counts in the same row where the solution is something like.

```
SELECT
    sum(case when rqbg = 'B' and rxbg = 'G' and rxmid is not null then 1 else 0 end) AS btg_changed,
    sum(case when rqbg = 'B' and rbg = 'G' and rxmid is not null then 1 else 0 end) AS btg_possible,
FROM fact 
where dt between '2021-04-01' and '2021-04-28'
and sender_account_id = 111111;
```

I want to do this but only sum up when a specific parameter, `rmid`,  is distinct.

I can do this using `UNION ALL`, for example:

```
SELECT count(DISTINCT rmid) AS "btg_changed"
from fact
where rqbg = 'B' 
and rbg = 'G' 
and rxmid is not null 
and rxbg = 'G'

UNION ALL

SELECT count(DISTINCT rmid) AS "btg_possible"
from fact
where rqbg = 'B' 
and rbg = 'G' 
and rxmid is not null
```

The problem here is that this latter approach does not actually make each value its own column - every count is in the same column which.

So how can I do this where I only count distinct rows based on `rmid` but I am also getting each count in its own column. The final result should just be one row with a few different counts. I have a few other things I want to ask but only included the two selects for clarity.

I am using Impala.

I have also changed some of the column names to obfuscate what I am working with a little so apologies if it is confusing.

Answer (score 1):

Just use conditions:

```
select count(case when rxbg = 'G' then rmid end) AS btg_changed,
       count(distinct rmid) as btg_possible
from fact
where rqbg = 'B' and rbg = 'G' and rxmid is not null
```

Comment: This was so close to working. I ended up finding that
```
select count(distinct case when rxbg = 'G' and rqbg = 'B' and rbg = 'G' then rmid end) AS btg_changed,
       count(distinct case when rqbg = 'B' and rbg = 'G' then rtpb_msg_id end) as btg_possible
from fact
where rxmid is not null 
```
works perfectly. Thank you. I had to keep the conditions outside because I have more counts.

Comment: @aaaaaaaaaron_g . . . You have redundant conditions in the `case` expression.  This answer refactors them in the `WHERE` which should make the query more efficient.

Comment: Thank you, what I meant to specify is that its not redundant because I need to count a lot of other things that do not have those conditions.

Comment: @aaaaaaaaaron_g . . . You refactor the common conditions in the `where` and then use `case` for the individual ones in the count.  This version corresponds exactly to your `union all` version (although that might not be equivalent to your first query).